# gcc can't find libcurl header file in the directory it is located

Tags: c++, gcc, header, libcurl

I am trying to compile a cpp using with the following command:

```
g++ -IC:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\include\curl -LC:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\lib program.cpp
```

this program has a header file which uses libcurl. the curl library is at -

```
C:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\include\curl\curl.h
```

gcc gives the following error even though curl.h is in the path -I

```
mylibrary.h:26:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the path to curl.h?

Comment: Any spaces in that `XXX`? Not used to seeing \ before the C in a Windows file system.

Comment: No spaces, -IC:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\include\curl doesn't work either

Comment: Your path should be `-IC:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\include`.

Comment: Thank you! that works but now i'm getting the same error with json/json.h

Answer (score 0):

The error message means the file `curl/curl.h` could not be found in the search path specified by -I.  You updated the question with the path to the file so the command should be:

```
g++ -IC:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\include -LC:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\lib program.cpp
```

Also, can you please try using \ instead of / as path separator in your mylibrary.h file:

```
#include <curl\curl.h>
```

Comment: what do you mean "out the trailing curl"?

Comment: I mean remove.  First step, per my initial comment, is to find the path to the curl.h.

Comment: C:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\include\curl\curl.h

Comment: This means it should be `-IC:\Users\XXX\libcurl-7.56.0\libcurl-7.56.0\include`.  I don't know if gcc on WIndows that require you to add the leading `\\`.

Comment: i mentioned above that doesnt work either